# SQL: Hierarchical query with multiple roots / parents

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table describing elements organized in a tree-like structure:

```
ID, PARENT_ID, NAME  
0   null       TOP  
1   0          A  
2   0          B  
3   0          C  
4   1          AA  
5   2          BA 
6   3          CA  
7   6          CAA
...
```

There can be many levels in this hierarchy.

Suppose there is a list of elements (say IDs 2 and 3) for which I would like to get all child records from the table.

Something like this:

```
select *
from MY_TABLE 
start with PARENT_ID in (2,3)
connect by PARENT_ID = prior ID
```

will return:

```
ID, PARENT_ID, NAME 
5   2          BA
6   3          CA
7   6          CAA
```

However, I want the each output record to be mapped to the original parent from my list (2,3) so that the output would look like this:

```
ORIGINAL_PARENT_ID, ID, PARENT_ID, NAME 
2                   5   2          BA
3                   6   3          CA
3                   7   6          CAA
```

How can it be done?

Comment: What SQL engine are you using? MS SQL Server, MySQL, PL/SQL...? Also, won't 0 be the ORIGINAL_PARENT_ID for everything?

Comment: I'm using PL/SQL. Yes, 0 would be the root element for everything, however I would like to start selecting chidren from the middle of the hierarchy, i.e. from elements 2 and 3 in my example. Since I start from 2 and 3, I see them as "original parents".

Comment: @user1949013 shouldnt the last row in your example be original parent = 3?

Comment: Yes, it should be 3 in the last row. Fixed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`connect_by_root` may be what you're after?

```
SQL> select t.*, connect_by_root parent_id as ORIGINAL_PARENT_ID
  2  from MY_TABLE  t
  3  start with PARENT_ID in (2,3)
  4  connect by PARENT_ID = prior ID
  5  /

        ID  PARENT_ID NAM ORIGINAL_PARENT_ID
---------- ---------- --- ------------------
         5          2 BA                   2
         6          3 CA                   3
         7          6 CAA                  3
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your names are really as you have them, then the problem can be done without `connect by`.  You can use simple string manipulation.

```
with ToFind (
    select 'C' as parent from dual union all
    select 'B' as parent from dual
   )
select t.*
from t join
     ToFind tf
     on t.name like tf.parent, 100)||'%' and t.name <> tf.parent
```

Comment: I used those names as an example. In my real data they can be anything. Thanks for suggestion.